# collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath -> CGSize Strange behaviour

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

So it's interesting i am trying to use `collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath` to display only one item at a time in `collectionView` and scroll horizontally, I have tried this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc]init];
    
    flowLayout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
    flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0.0;
    
    flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0.0;
    
    _obj_CollectionView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    _obj_CollectionView.collectionViewLayout = flowLayout;
    
    self.obj_CollectionView.delegate = self;
    self.obj_CollectionView.dataSource = self;
    _obj_CollectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}


-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return CGSizeMake(collectionView.frame.size.width, collectionView.frame.size.height);
}
```

Here is collectionView screenshot:

[image]

Here purple color is my cell and red color is my `collectionView` but I want purple color in whole.

so please guide me. I am confused. :)

Comment: can you try to print your collection view frame in sizeForItemAtIndexPath and compare it in viewDidAppear?

Comment: i tried it's both frame are same

Comment: Ok can you print the headerview and footerview size of the  collectionview

Comment: Or section header size

Comment: there is no section header or foote view

Comment: how you setting up the ui components?

Comment: nothing at cell for row index just one view is there. nothing all

Comment: based on my experience you have to create custom class for `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` so it will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                           minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 1.0
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout
    collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
    minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 1.0
}
```

ViewDidload:

```
layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 20
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 10
```

CellforrowAtIndexPath:

```
cell.image.clipsToBounds = true
cell.contentView.frame = cell.bounds
```

Comment: What is "CellforrowAtIndexPath:" ?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you don't need to create an object of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` programmatically. Also no need for the code written in `viewDidLoad()`. All this you can do using `storyboard` and `delegate` methods.

Below is the code for your problem:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}

extension ViewController : UICollectionViewDataSource
{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return 10
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = (indexPath.item % 2 == 0) ? UIColor.purple : UIColor.blue
        return cell
    }
}

extension ViewController : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
    {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width, height: collectionView.bounds.height)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat
    {
        return 0
    }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets
    {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    }
}
```

**Storyboard screenshot:**

[image]

**Output screen:**

[image]

Comment: still not remain same

Comment: What is the issue you are facing with this?

Comment: the screen shot that i have posted. i got same cell. view is not in purple color throughout whole cell. it;s having some space as you can see in the screenshot

Comment: I have updated the answer and added a new method to UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout. Have a look.

Answer (score 0):

I made a little proof of concept and it works as expected for me.
Maybe something is wrong with your `CollectionViewCell` (wrong / missing Constraints)?

```
import UIKit


class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0

        collectionView?.collectionViewLayout = layout
        collectionView?.isPagingEnabled = true
    }


    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }


    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }


    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = (indexPath.item % 2 == 0) ? UIColor.purple : UIColor.blue

        return cell
    }
}

extension CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return self.view.frame.size
    }
}
```

Comment: i have set out proper constraints and checked multiple time but don't getting. tried this also.

Answer (score 0):

You have some debugging options to check what is the reason for that:

- `NSLog()` frame of your `UICollectionView`
- `NSLog()` `CGSize` to check the actual size returned
- Try setting hard-coded size to check the behavior.
- If using `autoLayout`, try after removing your constraints.

Hope this will help.

Comment: tried everything but still not able to figured out :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i figured it out.
Let me post the layout of my storyboard first.

I took a iPhone6 layout and gave the following constraints to the collection view

## Setting Layout

1. Fixed the collection view's width to that of the view's

   [image: Image 1]
2. Next i Fixed the aspect ratio of the collection view, so that it's always a square

[image: Image 2]

3. Finally we added the top, trailing and leading constraints.

[image: Image3]

Now, I changed the layout to horizontal scroll from vertical and added the following code.

## Code Implementation

```
 #import "ViewController.h"

 @interface ViewController ()<UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource>

 @property (nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UICollectionView *clcnView;

 @end

 @implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

#pragma mark - Collection View methods- 

 -(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
     static NSString *reuse = @"cell";
     UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuse forIndexPath:indexPath];
     cell.backgroundColor = randomColor();
     return cell;
 }


-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
     return 10;
 }


 - (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     CGFloat fl = self.clcnView.frame.size.width;
     CGSize mElementSize = CGSizeMake(fl-1, fl-1);
     return mElementSize;
 }
 - (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
     return 1.0;
 }

   - (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout  minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
     return 1.0;
 }

  - (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
     return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,0,0);
 }


 UIColor * randomColor(){
     return [UIColor colorWithRed:arc4random_uniform(255)/255.0f green:arc4random_uniform(255)/255.0f blue:arc4random_uniform(255)/255.0f alpha:1.0];
 }


 @end
```

And that did the trick. 
Here are the screenshots

## in IPhone

[image: Screenshot 1] [image: Screenshot2]

## in iPad

[image: iPad Screenshot1] [image: iPad Screenshot2]

I Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: did u follow all the steps mentioned here. 
Its working fine here.

Comment: Also, if you have implemented any layout code, as in custom layout please remove them, and let the layout remain as flow (default) from storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this it will helps you.

```
#pragma mark -- Collection View Delegate and datasource method --
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 10;
}


- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";


    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UILabel *title = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, cell.bounds.size.width - 40, 22)];
    title.tag = 200;
    title.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:title];

    return cell;
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CGFloat width = self.collectionViewSearchCity.frame.size.width/2-20;
    return CGSizeMake(width, 50.0);
}



- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 15, 0,15);
}
```